# Script for detecting the screen size,and change css according to screen size

Tags: javascript, css

I got this script for detecting the size of the window -

```js
function myFunction()
{
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;

    if (w = 768) {
        document.getElementById("container").style.height = "15.155em";
    } else if (w = 1024) {
        document.getElementById("container").style.height = "25.155em";
    } else if (w = 1366) {
        document.getElementById("container").style.height = "35.155em";
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div id="container" style="width:50px;border:2px solid black;">
  </div>
</body>
```

What i would like to happen,is each time the height of the div would change,according to the size of window.

Whats happening now,is on every screen i run the website its showing me as if the screen size is the "768"

Comment: Why not use height:100% ? You need then of course set the body to height: 100% to make this work. You can also use the @media rule: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1

Comment: its a matter of making it responsive

Comment: use css `height:100%;` or `height:100vh;`.

Comment: the @media ruleset is especially for creating responsive layouts

Comment: Jankapunkt can you give a link to some website with most usefull @media rules ? Ive checked a bunch,and nothing

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

is for the explaination and there you find it also in the css reference for parameter definitions

Comment: Jankapunkt thanks,but its too complicated for me,im a CSS3 newbi,and im in hurry to finish this project

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript for this: it can be done entirely with css. You have a few options (that I can think of right now):

1. Using the amazing [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) classes ([example](https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/))
2. Setting height to 100% on the element itself and all parents (try the snippet below)
3. Using the [vh](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) viewport units (1vh = 1% of viewport height)

Hope that helps!

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS instead of using JS.
Use the following CSS to fit the DIV to whatever size of the screen is.

```
    #container
    {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto; 
   }
```

Also you can use `height:100vh` but this Unit will not be support in older browser.

Thanks

Comment: Actully without the height given its not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

because actual browser width is always lesser than screen resolution ,
and u are using screen resolution for comparison.

```
if (w = 768)
else if (w = 1024)
else if (w = 1366)
```

Either use

```
if(w<768)
//do something
else if(w<1024)
//do something
else if(w<1366)
//do something
else
//default
```

Or better use

```
screen.width
screen.height
```

if you want to use = as comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
{
    .container
    {
        height: 15.155em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
{
    .container
    {
        height: 25.155em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in a if condition to evaluate there should be == and not =. What you have used is an assignment operator and not comparision.

Please correct the code as below

```
function myFunction()
{
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;

    if (w == 768) {
        document.getElementById("container").style.height = "15.155em";
    } else if (w == 1024) {
        document.getElementById("container").style.height = "25.155em";
    } else if (w == 1366) {
        document.getElementById("container").style.height = "35.155em";
    }
}
```

As other members suggested mediaQueries is a good option in case you are looking to make it responsive.